# Client-Server Secure communication within application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, security, server, database-connection

I want to create a game within the Unity game engine in C# with .NET where I can securely connect out to a private server, and read and write data from/to the server. I understand how to do this in a non-secure way, where I would setup a private SQL database with a webpage interface between the two.

My problem comes here, I know if I want the web interface to be public, I need credentials to connect to the server, such as an Auth key, or username and password. However, in order to use those, then the auth-key would need to ship with the game as a file, or would need to be written directly into the codebase. I know that users can decompile games, and access these files and get the credentials if I include them, which means that option is off the table as far as I am aware.

It is my understanding that even with this layer between the database and the client, someone could still find the url for the interface between them, and then send custom function calls to this url as I will be doing in the game program. Wouldn't this lead to the same conclusion as having the database be open?

If anyone has answers to this, or resources where I can learn about this process, please let me know! I have never done server-side programming before and have also never thought about security before in my life.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you should not embed authentication keys into your apps.  Where you're falling down is in exposing your database to the world.  Don't do this.  Instead, hide it behind a web server that serves only json data files.  This way you can take advantage of the web server's authentication and **session** protocols.

Since you're already working with C#, I would suggest looking into [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and specifically about [WebAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).  But I would probably recommend node.js for lightweight microservices.

Comment: I understand that I want to hide the database behind a web server, however, wouldn't this have the same issue? If it is a public web server, then anyone can access it and pass function calls to the program just as I am and get access to the data. And if it is a private web server, I have the same credential issue. Please let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: The password you give to your user/app to use your website is not the same one you give your website to use the database.  Also, if you write your website correctly, then your user can only run the preset sql scripts/functions that you give the site.  You can even go so far (and I recommend this) to give each unique user/app instance their own authentication id, either through passwords or generating a machine key in your app.

Comment: Sorry, when I talk about users, I don't really mean that they will have user accounts or anything, I want to just host to anonymous users that come across the site. I guess what I am saying is, if I need to be able to add and delete information from an SQL database, then even with the preset sql scripts/functions, couldn't they utilize those preset scripts/functions to add/remove things that I don't want them to?